# CSS3 Linear gradient function (darker line between image and gradient)

Tags: css, linear-gradients

So I am trying to make a linear gradient from an image with a solid color, however, there's a darker line visable where the color and gradient cross:

example:

[image: the line]

```
The CSS:


.green-background {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3c7c3f, #ffffff);
    background: #3c7c3f;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3c7c3f, #ffffff);
    padding: 100px 0;
}
```

How to solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: can you share the full code including the image also ?

Answer (score 0):

It's actually an optical illusion. If you check the HSL values pixel per pixel, you'll see that the color isn't actually getting darker, and the gradient works as expected. I guess it's just the way our eyes perceive such a drastic change in colors (dark green to white).

I suggest try adding a color in between these two or maybe make the top green color a bit lighter. Try to experiment until you find a good match.

Comment: What tool can you use to check the HSL values?

Comment: @RBarryYoung I use [Sip](https://sipapp.io/), a simple colour-picker for macOS. Apart from hex values, one can also read colours in HSL.